# How to extend modal background when modal grows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Similar question:

[Modal dialog- How to get modal's background to extend 100% with scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601953/modal-dialog-how-to-get-modals-background-to-extend-100-with-scrolling)

With bootstrap when you show a modal it covers the rest of the screen's content with a gray background.  However, if you show a modal, and then add contents to that modal until it extends below the bottom of the visible window, when you scroll down to view this content, the gray background does not extend below the original size of the modal.  Instead you see gray background down to the size of the window, and then the regular background color for the site below that.

Is there a way to make this gray background grow when the modal grows?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals as much as I edit the content for this modal everything looks as it should.
can you provide a piece of code or a link for this?

Comment: You need to add max height to the modal and the modal will then scroll the content without the background being affected.

Comment: Yeah I tried it in codeply and couldn't reproduce the problem.  Stuart's solution did work, however, I just added "max-height: none;" to modals and it solved the problem.  If you want to write it up I'll mark as answer!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must call `.data('bs.modal').handleUpdate();` on your modal element while adding your dynamic content.

Example:

`function addContent() {
    // add dynamic content
    $('.modal-body').append('<p>lorem ipsum...</p>'); 
    // update modal backdrop
    $('.modal').data('bs.modal').handleUpdate();
}`